# Fitting multiple distributions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-fitting

I have a situation where two or more nd arrays, with some coefficients, should add up (roughly) to a third array.

```
array1*c1 + array2*c2 ... = array3
```

I'm looking for the `c1` and `c2` that make the first two arrays best approximate `array3`. I'm sure some way of doing this exists in scipy, but I'm not sure where to start. Is there are specific module I should begin with?

Comment: Not sure how to implement but check out `optimize.fsolve` in scipy. Make a function that returns `array3-array1*c1+array2*c2(...)` since fsolve finds the roots (i.e. where function = 0), and pass fsolve this function with initial guesses. You may have to sum the array before returning and this could introduce bad behaviour e.g. an array containing equal +ve and -ve values. Just a suggestion therefore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[numpy.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) solves this for you. Object-oriented wrappers for that function, as well as more advanced regression models, are available in both [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) and [StatsModels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/regression.html).

(Disclaimer: I'm a scikit-learn developer, so this is not the most unbiased advice ever.)

Comment: Something that allows errors to be associated with array values would also help, I assume the later options do this?

Comment: @Shep: what do you mean by that?

Comment: basically looking for a way to weight the values I'm fitting. but maybe that's for another question

Comment: You mean a weight per sample that determines how much it influences the function found? I think some of the regression learners in scikit-learn can do that, but I'm not sure which and how useful they are to you (I'm more into classification than regression).

Comment: Exactly. Weighting is definitely important in classification too, so I'd assume it exitst.

Comment: @Shep: oh, there sure are classifiers in scikit-learn that do this; you can recognize them from the `sample_Weight` parameter given to the `fit` method. Regression models should follow the same API.

Answer (score 0):

This is just linear regression (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares).

Let the matrix `A` be have columns of `array1, array2, ...`
Let the vector `a` be `array3` and `x` be a the column vector `[c1,c2,...]'`.

You want to solve the problem `min_{x} (Ax-a)^2`.

Taking the derivative and setting to zero gives `0=A'Ax-A'a`, which gives the solution `x=(A'A)^{-1}A'a`.

In numpy this is `numpy.linalg.solve(numpy.dot(A.T,A),numpy.dot(A.T,a))`.